Why won't my c program update the mouse position?
I need help with my c mouse position code so that it works properly. The mouse position is supposed to update when you move it and should keep updating the position as you move. The mouse left and right button clicked works but whenever I move the mouse it just keeps outputting the same position. How can I fix this. code output sample
code:
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <xdo.h>

int main() {
    char info[10];
    int dev_mouse = -1;
    dev_mouse = open("/dev/input/mice", O_RDWR);

    while (1) {
        read(dev_mouse, info, 3);

        if (0x01 & info[0]) printf("%s", "left button down\n");
        if (0x02 & info[0]) printf("%s", "right button down\n");

        // Read in positions of your mouse and print them;
        int x, y, scrn;
        xdo_t *handle = xdo_new(NULL);
        xdo_get_mouse_location(handle, &x, &y, &scrn);
        xdo_free(handle);
        printf("Mouse Position: x = %4d, y = %4d\n", x, y);
    }

    close(dev_mouse);

    return 0;
}


I already compiled the code with -lxdo -lX11 at the end, and I run the code with sudo. I have updated all of the packages. I am using fedora btw.
